# Match specific alphabets followed by underscore in node.js

Tags: regex, match, nodes

*
Need to match all those variables that contains either _web or _mb
*

```
const paragraph = 'vendors/photographer/12342323123/photos/3213/sdf32sd3_mb.jpg';
or
const paragraph = 'vendors/photographer/12342323123/photos/3213/sdf32sd3_web.jpg';
```

- This is what i did
  regex = /(_web|_mb)/g 
  *

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const paragraph = 'vendors/photographer/12342323123/photos/3213/sdf32sd3_mb.jpg';
const regex = /_*(web|mb)/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);
if(found !=null){
  console.log("compress image");
}else{
  console.log("do not compress image");
}

console.log(found);
```

*
Got the perfect by using the above mentioned regex.
1- _*(web|mb) means underscore followed by alphabets web or mb
2- | is used for or in regex which needs to be placed inside a round bracket
3- g at the end is for global
*

Comment: Your regex matches `webmaster` or `embedded`, are you sure you want to match them?